# Elastic search query not working with synonym_analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, analyzer, synonym

I have a query that looks like this:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "product.ref",
    "product.urls.*",
    "product.i18ns.*.title",
    "product_sale_elements.quantity",
    "product_sale_elements.prices.*.price",
    "product_sale_elements.listen_price.*",
    "product.images.image_url",
    "product.image_count",
    "product.images.visible",
    "product.images.position"
  ],
  "min_score": 0.1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "product.is_visible": true
          }
        }
      ], 
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "13114140",
            "fields": [
              "product.i18ns.en_US.title.analyzed",
              "product.ref",
              "categories.i18ns.en_US.title.analyzed"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "categories.i18ns.en_US.title.raw"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this works fairly well for me, i'm happy with it. Although I would like to add a `synonym_analyzer`. Problem is when I add it like this:

```
...
 {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "13114140",
            "fields": [
              "product.i18ns.de_AT.title.analyzed",
              "product.ref",
              "categories.i18ns.de_AT.title.analyzed"
            ],
            "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
          }
        }
...
```

The whole query seems to crumble and I dont get back anything as response. Why is this happening?

Comment: can you please share some sample index data, and expected search result OR please tell exactly what issue you are facing in the search results ?

Comment: I think my question is, why is it that I get back 0 results when I add ```"analyzer":"synonym_analyzer"```